# Dispatch event occurs multiple times

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using a dispatch event in Symfony, And I don't understand because I have the `kernel.response` twice.

**Controller:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/evento", name="evento")
 */
public function eventoAction()
{
    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    $subscriber = new StoreSubriber();
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);
    $event = new FilterOrderEvent($order);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER,$event);
    return $this->render('::event.html.twig');
}
```

**Subscriber:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Events;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class StoreSubriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'kernel.request' => array(
                array('onKernelResponsePre', -10),
                array('onKernelResponseMid', 5),
                array('onKernelResponsePost', 0),
            ),
            'store.order' => array('onStoreOrder', 0),
        );
    }

    public function onKernelResponsePre(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "onKernelResponsePre";
    }

    public function onKernelResponseMid(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "onKernelResponseMid";
    }

    public function onKernelResponsePost(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "onKernelResponsePost";
    }

    public function onStoreOrder(FilterOrderEvent $event)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "ORDER";
    }
}
```

**service.yml:**

```
services:
    user_check_token:
        class: AppBundle\Events\StoreSubriber
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

**My Output:**

```
onKernelResponseMid
onKernelResponsePost
onKernelResponsePre
ORDER
Events ( twig )


onKernelResponseMid
onKernelResponsePost
onKernelResponsePre
```

My question is, why am I seeing `onKernelResponseMid`, `onKernelResponsePost`, and `onKernelResponsePre` twice?

Comment: I guess it's a sub-request. For instance, because you use `{{ render(controller(...)) }}` in your code or to render the web dev toolbar

Comment: @WouterJ i tried ti empty cache and use prod environment, But I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say because you subscribed to the event twice.

- First inside your `eventoAction` `$dispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);`
- Second with Tagging your subscriber in your configuration `tags: - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }`

Try removing this `$dispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);` from eventoAction.

### edit

**other possible reasons**

- multiple kernel event event can fire for each request, symfony can do subrequest, anywhere during running the code. This can be also in twig like this: `{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles') }}`. As this is another real request the event will fire. To handle this you need to add conditions to your subscriber to filter only request which you want to handle
- if you use prod environment clear cache as your twice registered subscriber can be cached.

### edit 2

**how to debug subrequest**

To easily find out if there where any sub request going on, you can look in the web debug toolbar.

- go to the fullpage view (click any section)
- upper left corner find link "last 10" (meaning show last 10 requests)
- at glance you should see how each request went one after another, with they urls and times, and possibility to go to that request full page debug.

This way you'll should be able to find if there are any subrequests and where they originated from.

Comment: @monkeyUser another thing can be a subrequest in your twig template. something like this inside template will do another request `{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles'`

Comment: ok if I do `$res = new JsonResponse();
        $res->setData(
            array('data' => 'ok')
        );
        return $res;` I have echo once. But Why twig or render re-call `kernel.request`?

Comment: it's probably because when you call `render(controller())` you're issuing a sub request which is an entirely new request that will get the subscribed event again